# if else statements

Tags: vhdl, clock

I am trying to understand how if else statements and clock work. My application accepts chars as input (), and for each char the application should go into the if else statement. Here the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity xillydemo is
  port (
     PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
 PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
 PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
 PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
 PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
 GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
 PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
 PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0));
end xillydemo;

architecture sample_arch of xillydemo is

  component xillybus
    port (
      PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
      PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
      PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
      PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
      PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
      GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
      PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
      PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
      bus_clk : OUT std_logic;
      quiesce : OUT std_logic;

      user_r_read_8_rden : OUT std_logic;
      user_r_read_8_empty : IN std_logic;
      user_r_read_8_data : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
      user_r_read_8_eof : IN std_logic;
      user_r_read_8_open : OUT std_logic;
      user_w_write_8_wren : OUT std_logic;
      user_w_write_8_full : IN std_logic;
      user_w_write_8_data : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
      user_w_write_8_open : OUT std_logic);
  end component;

  component fifo_8x2048
    port (
      clk: IN std_logic;
      srst: IN std_logic;
      din: IN std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      wr_en: IN std_logic;
      rd_en: IN std_logic;
      dout: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      full: OUT std_logic;
      empty: OUT std_logic);
  end component;


-- Synplicity black box declaration
  attribute syn_black_box : boolean;
  attribute syn_black_box of fifo_8x2048: component is true;

  signal bus_clk :  std_logic;
  signal quiesce : std_logic;

  signal reset_8 : std_logic;

  signal ram_addr : integer range 0 to 31;

  signal user_r_read_8_rden  :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_empty :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_data  :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_8_eof   :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_open  :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_wren :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_full :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_w_write_8_open :  std_logic;
  signal wr_en               :  std_logic := '0';
  signal din                 :  std_logic_vector(user_w_write_8_data'range) := (others => '0');


begin
  xillybus_ins : xillybus
    port map (
      -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_read_8
      -- FPGA to CPU signals:
      user_r_read_8_rden => user_r_read_8_rden,
      user_r_read_8_empty => user_r_read_8_empty,
      user_r_read_8_data => user_r_read_8_data,
      user_r_read_8_eof => user_r_read_8_eof,
      user_r_read_8_open => user_r_read_8_open,

      -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_write_8
      -- CPU to FPGA signals:
      user_w_write_8_wren => user_w_write_8_wren,
      user_w_write_8_full => user_w_write_8_full,
      user_w_write_8_data => user_w_write_8_data,
      user_w_write_8_open => user_w_write_8_open,

      -- General signals
      PCIE_PERST_B_LS => PCIE_PERST_B_LS,
      PCIE_REFCLK_N => PCIE_REFCLK_N,
      PCIE_REFCLK_P => PCIE_REFCLK_P,
      PCIE_RX_N => PCIE_RX_N,
      PCIE_RX_P => PCIE_RX_P,
      GPIO_LED => GPIO_LED,
      PCIE_TX_N => PCIE_TX_N,
      PCIE_TX_P => PCIE_TX_P,
      bus_clk => bus_clk,
      quiesce => quiesce
   );

  process (bus_clk)

    variable counter : integer := 0;
    variable my_buffer_a :  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    variable my_buffer_b :  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    begin 

          user_r_read_8_eof <= user_r_read_8_empty and not(user_w_write_8_open);
          wr_en <= user_w_write_8_wren;

          if (bus_clk'event and bus_clk = '1') then    
              if (counter = 0) then
                  my_buffer_a := "00110010";--2 --user_w_write_8_data;
                  counter := 1;
              elsif (counter = 1) then
                  my_buffer_b := "00110011"; --3--user_w_write_8_data;
                  counter := 2;
              elsif (counter = 2) then
                  din <= "00110100";--4 -- my_buffer_a;
                  counter := 3;
              elsif (counter = 3) then
                  din <= "00110101"; --5 -- my_buffer_b;
                  counter := 0;
              end if;
          end if;
    end process;

--  8-bit loopback

  fifo_8 : fifo_8x2048
    port map(
      clk        => bus_clk,
      srst       => reset_8,
      din        => din,
      wr_en      => wr_en,
      rd_en      => user_r_read_8_rden,
      dout       => user_r_read_8_data,
      full       => user_w_write_8_full,
      empty      => user_r_read_8_empty
  );

reset_8 <= not (user_w_write_8_open or user_r_read_8_open);


end sample_arch;
```

The problem is that, by given as input "John", the application outputs 55455. This means that my application never goes into if (counter = 0) and elsif (counter = 1). Any reason why?

Comment: You assigned `my_buffer_a` and `my_buffer_b` instead of `din`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a switch statement for the embedded if... elseif statements.  It is not obvious to me what language you are using.  Switch statements have many different cases, e.g., test counter for being equal to 1, and executing statements if it is.  After the statements there is a "break" which keeps the subsequent checks for "counter equal to" statements from executing.  In the language you are using look for "switch" or "case" and I think you will find it.  If you don't let me know what language you are using and I will look.

I found [this](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/sequential.html#case) which is a nice example of what I think you are trying to do.  I took your statements and reformatted them into a VHDL case statement using the example as a guide:

```
case counter is
when 0 =>
  my_buffer_a := "00110010";--2 --user_w_write_8_data;
  counter := 1;
when 1 =>
  my_buffer_b := "00110011"; --3--user_w_write_8_data;
  counter := 2;
when 2 =>
  din <= "00110100";--4 -- my_buffer_a;
  counter := 3;
when 3 =>
  din <= "00110101"; --5 -- my_buffer_b;
  counter := 0;
when others =>
  null;
end case;
```

This should replace your if statements between

```
if (bus_clk'event and bus_clk = '1') then
```

and its associated

```
end if;
```

Note the last item in the case statement, "when others", is a "safety valve" for when a value which you had not anticipated for counter is tested.

Comment: Hi user34299, while you are allowed to add more than one answer, for follow up answers you should edit your answer and using second answers for e.g. a different approach/solution.

Answer (score 0):

elseif statements are just a series of if statements.  It appears to me that when your code checks counter = 0 it satisfies the first if statement, executing the subsequent code.  However, you then set counter to 1 and it immediately encounters the next if statement checking it the counter is 1, which counter now is.  You repeat this process.  Ultimately your code gets to the end and counter is set to 0 but the code has been executed for counter = 3.

I suggest that once an if or elseif statement's code has been executed that you break away so that the subsequent elseif statements are not executed.

Comment: how do I break else if statement?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.8 If statement, "An if statement selects for execution one or none of the enclosed sequences of statements, depending on the value of one or more corresponding conditions." ..."For the execution of an if statement, the condition specified after if, and any conditions specified after elsif, are evaluated in succession (treating a final else as elsif TRUE then) until one evaluates to TRUE or all conditions are evaluated and yield FALSE. "